# TSQL: Using a Table in a Variable in a Function

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, variables, dynamic

I'm trying to do a select from a table that will need to be in a variable.  I'm working with tables that are dynamically created from an application.  The table will be named CMDB_CI_XXX, where XXX will be an integer value based on a value in another table.  The ultimate goal is to get the CI Name from the table.

I've tried passing the pieces that make up the table name to a function and string them together and then return the name value, but I'm not allowed to use an EXEC statement in a function.

This is what I want to execute to get the name value back:

```
Select [Name] from 'CMDB_CI_' + C.CI_TYPE_ID + Where CI_ID = c.CI_ID
```

This is the code in the SP that I'd like to use the function in to get the name value:

```
SELECT  
  CI_ID,
  C.CI_TYPE_ID,
  CI_CUSTOM_ID,
  STATUS,
  CI_TYPE_NAME,
  --(Select [Name] from CMDB_CI_ + C.CI_TYPE_ID + Where CI_ID = c.CI_ID)   
FROM [footprints].[dbo].[CMDB50_CI_COMMON] c
join [footprints].[dbo].[CMDB50_CI_TYPE] t
on c.CI_TYPE_ID = t.CI_TYPE_ID 
where status <> 'retired'
order by CI_TYPE_NAME
```

I'm not sure what to do with this.  Please help?

Thanks,
Jennifer

Comment: wow, this sounds bad, why are the tables created dynamically in the application -- if they differ on 3 characters you should have a table named `CMDB_CI` and a column that is 3 characters long to store the code.  You don't want to be dynamically creating tables in SQL.  That said I'll answer your question, what platform are you using, SQL Server, DB2, Oracle or mySQL or Progress?

Comment: You can't parameterise tables in an SQL Query. And I agree with @Hogan - it looks like you've ended up with some data that you'd like to be able to query actually embedded in a table name - that's a bad mixup of data and metadata.

Comment: I'm using SQL Server 2008. I asked the Support team of the application why this was set up this way and was told that because table is set up for attributes and each type can have different attributes then the column names may be different for each attribute. One may have a column name of "Color" and another might be "SerialNumber". But I completely agree with you. I would have set it all up so very differently.

Comment: @Jennifer - Attribute name should be in a different table. This is clearly a bad design. SQL does let you "dynamic" a statement as shown in my answer.  It will be slower than non-dynamic SQL would be.

Answer (score 1):

```
-- This part would be a SP parameter I expect
DECLARE @tableName varchar(100)
SET @tableName = 'CMDB_CI_508'

-- Main SP code
DECLARE @sqlStm VARCHAR(MAX)

SET @sqlStm = 'SELECT * 
FROM '+ @tableName

EXEC (@sqlStm)
```

Fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/436a7/7

Comment: I'd do something like `Declare @suffix char(3), @tableName varchar(100); set @tableName = 'CMDB_CI_'+@suffix` which will make an injection attack much harder.

Comment: @KM - Yes that would be better just because it is "cleaner code."  I was just making an example of dynamic SQL here.  In terms of injection, a programer should just use parametrized queries and SPs -ALWAYS!!

Comment: That doesn't work.  The problem is I can't use an EXEC statement in a function. As far as I know if I pass the table name to a stored procedure, I can't do that from a select clause.  I need to do this for each row that is being returned from the table.  What I really need is something like this: SELECT  
  CI_ID,
  C.CI_TYPE_ID,
  CI_CUSTOM_ID,
  STATUS,
  CI_TYPE_NAME,
  UDF_GetCIName (C.CI_TYPE_ID C.CI_ID)
FROM [footprints].[dbo].[CMDB50_CI_COMMON] c
join [footprints].[dbo].[CMDB50_CI_TYPE] t
on c.CI_TYPE_ID = t.CI_TYPE_ID 
where status <> 'retired'
order by CI_TYPE_NAME

Comment: @Jennifer - ok and the two table names are dynamic -- what is dynamic about the function?  What does the function do?

Answer (score 0):

First off, yes, I know it's a bad design. I didn't design it. It came with the problem tracking software that my company bought for our call center.  So I gave up altogether on the approach I was going for and used a cursor to pull all the the names from the various tables into one temp table and then used said temp table to join to the original query.

```
ALTER Proc [dbo].[CI_CurrentItems]

As

Declare @CIType nvarchar(6)
Declare @Qry nvarchar(100)
/*
Create Table Temp_CI 
( T_CI_ID int,
  T_CI_Type_ID int,
  T_Name nvarchar(400)
)
*/

Truncate Table Temp_CI

Declare CI_Cursor Cursor For 
select distinct CI_TYPE_ID  FROM [footprints].[dbo].[CMDB50_CI_COMMON]
where STATUS <> 'Retired'

Open CI_Cursor

Fetch Next from CI_Cursor into @CIType

While @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
Set @Qry = 'Select CI_ID, CI_Type_ID, Name from Footprints.dbo.CMDB50_CI_' + @CIType 
Insert into Temp_CI Exec (@Qry)
Fetch Next from CI_Cursor into @CIType
END

Close CI_Cursor
Deallocate CI_Cursor

SELECT  CI_ID,
    C.CI_TYPE_ID,
    CI_CUSTOM_ID,
    STATUS,
    CI_TYPE_NAME,
    T_Name
FROM [footprints].[dbo].[CMDB50_CI_COMMON] c
JOIN [footprints].[dbo].[CMDB50_CI_TYPE] t
ON c.CI_TYPE_ID = t.CI_TYPE_ID 
JOIN Temp_CI tc
ON c.CI_ID = tc.T_CI_ID
AND t.CI_TYPE_ID = tc.T_CI_TYPE_ID
WHERE STATUS <> 'retired'
ORDER BY CI_TYPE_NAME
```